# If a macro is defined in one of the linked header file will it be defined in main file too?

Tags: c++

Suppose a macro is defined in one header file, and I include the header in the main file. Will the macro be defined in my main file too?

Example code:
Header file:

```
#define header
```

Main file:

```
#include "Header file"

#ifdef header
// code1
#else
// code2
#endif
```

Q: Which code will be executed?

Comment: `// code 1` I guess.

Comment: A [preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor) is part of your compiler's tool chain. A preprocessor works on your files; it is not part of your files. The `#define` is a _preprocessor **directive**_ that turns `header` into a [macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace). So did you mean to ask: if a **macro** is defined in one header file, will it be defined when that header file is `#include`d in another file?

Comment: yes this is what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Out of curiosity: would you have had the same question if the macro was defined with a value, as in `#define PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884`? Would you hesitate before using `PI` in your source file with this setup? *NOTE: This is not the best way to define a constant; it's just for illustrative purposes.*

Answer (score 3):

`code1` would be executed.
Otherwise include guards would never work.

Using `#include` just copy&paste the content of the file you include, nothing else.
It is as if you would have written everything yourself into the main file.